# Compared data not populating offset column *VBA*

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I decided to post all of my code on this one, I've been bashing my head in on this for a few days and it's killing me. I have two very large columns which I aggregated from other columns to create unique cell values. I now need to compare one column of these unique cell values to the other column of unique cell values in order to find duplicates and print those duplicate cell values in an offset column. The code in this instance has an issue with my range, I've tried, for each, for, vlookup and index match, and I can't seem to get it right. The column sizes change week to week, so I can't hardcode the ranges.

Please help, thank you.

This was tagged as a duplicate question but I am not moving the data across sheets, only 8 columns to the left.

```
Sub DEV_CODE_DuplicateCheck()
    'VBA Speed up settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False



        Dim sht1 As Worksheet
        Dim sht2 As Worksheet
        Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
        Dim n As Long
        pluginOne = 2
        ipOne = 6
        portOne = 8
        uniqueIdOne = 46

        Dim WorkFile As String
        VRMFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

        'Unfilter original report to show all rows
        Workbooks(WorkFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
        Workbooks(WorkFile).Worksheets("Sheet2").AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")


    Dim noSep As String
    noSep = ""

    Cells(1, 2) = pluginOne
    Cells(1, 6) = ipOne
    Cells(1, 8) = portOne
    Cells(1, 46) = uniqueIdOne

    x = 2
    Do While Cells(x, pluginOne) <> ""
    Cells(x, uniqueIdOne) = Cells(x, pluginOne) & noSep & Cells(x, ipOne) & noSep & Cells(x, portOne)
    x = x + 1
    Loop
    Columns("AT:AT").EntireColumn.AutoFit


    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate


    pluginTwo = 3
    ipTwo = 30
    portTwo = 32
    uniqueIdTwo = 47

    Cells(2, 3) = pluginTwo
    Cells(2, 30) = ocisobIP
    Cells(2, 32) = portTwo
    Cells(1, 47) = uniqueIdTwo

    y = 2

    Do While Cells(y, pluginTwo) <> ""
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, uniqueIdTwo) = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(y, pluginTwo) & noSep & Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(y, ipTwo) & noSep & Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(y, portTwo)
    y = y + 1
    Loop
    Columns("AU:AU").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Range("au1").Select
        Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp

     ****EVERYTHING WORKS FINE TO THIS POINT*****

    Dim StartRange As Variant, j As Variant
    Dim CompareRange As Variant, i As Variant

    Set StartRange = Range("AT")
    Set CompareRange = Range("AU")

    For Each i In Selection
        For Each j In CompareRange
            If i = j Then i.Offset(0, -8) = i
        Next j
    Next i



    End Sub
```

Comment: The columns are thousands of rows long, I'm a bit burnt out so I'm having trouble even figuring out the best method for this compare to save processing time once the macro is run.

Comment: Use something like this,`Dim dic As Object
      Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 With dic
    For Each r In Range("AU1:AU" & Cells(Rows.Count, 47).End(xlUp).row)
       If .Exists(Trim(r)) Then
           r.Offset(, -8) = r
       Else
          .Add Trim(r), Trim(r)
       End If
    Next r
  End With`